# не получается добавить ATL simple object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atl

Создал ATL Project, в него пытаюсь добавить простой ATL объект.
Назвал компонент Indexer, вижла создает соответсвующий интерфейс и класс 
Однако в файле `Indexer.h` автогенерируется куча кода скучей ошибок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю почему вижла не видит соответствующие переменные\классы, она же вроде как их сама сделала.

код в `Index.h`

```
// Indexer.h : Declaration of the CIndexer

#pragma once
#include "resource.h"       // main symbols



#include "components_i.h"



#if defined(_WIN32_WCE) && !defined(_CE_DCOM) && !defined(_CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA)
#error "Single-threaded COM objects are not properly supported on Windows CE platform, such as the Windows Mobile platforms that do not include full DCOM support. Define _CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA to force ATL to support creating single-thread COM object's and allow use of it's single-threaded COM object implementations. The threading model in your rgs file was set to 'Free' as that is the only threading model supported in non DCOM Windows CE platforms."
#endif

using namespace ATL;


// CIndexer

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CIndexer :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CIndexer, &CLSID_Indexer>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IIndexer, &IID_IIndexer, &LIBID_componentsLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
    CIndexer()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(106)


BEGIN_COM_MAP(CIndexer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IIndexer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
END_COM_MAP()



    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
    }

public:



};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(Indexer), CIndexer)
```

Comment: Вы код покажите, а по скриншотам можно только гадать. А вообще не очень полагайтесь на визарды, они далеко не всегда создают рабочий код. Я бы сказал, 50/50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не определены GUIDы в `Indexer.h`, что, собственно, и говорится в сообщениях об ошибке. Хотя нужно еще глянуть `components_i.h`, но там явно тоже этого нет. Такие ляпы в автоматически сгенерированном коде совсем не редкость - стоит только чуть отойти от стандартных настроек визарда, и результат часто даже не компилируется.

Перенесите все макросы `DEFINE_GUID` в `stdafx.h`, и их же плюс `#include <initguid.h>` поместите в `stdafx.cpp`. Ну и на будущее имейте в виду, что сгенерированный код нужно отлаживать так же, как и свой.